# An error occurred while installing ruby-opencv (0.0.14)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, opencv, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm facing gem ruby-opencv installation issue

```
 Gem files will remain installed in /home/k2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/gems/ruby-opencv-0.0.14 for inspection.Results logged to /home/k2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/ruby-opencv-0.0.14/gem_make.out

 An error occurred while installing ruby-opencv (0.0.14), and Bundler cannot continue.

 Make sure that `gem install ruby-opencv -v '0.0.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried below one also

```
gem install ruby-opencv -v '0.0.14'

ruby -v => 2.1.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the opencv package from
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master using,

git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git

or clicking on download button in that same page.

And install the above package using http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

And then start to install the gem as below

**gem install ruby-opencv -- --with-opencv-dir=/usr/local.**

Now it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the Ruby `opencv` gem needs to compile native extensions, including the `opencv` tools, the `sqlite` database, the `python` language, `openssl` networking, and possibly access to your system's compiler such as `gcc`.

These extensions are generally easiest to diagnose by using `sudo`.

Try this if you can:

```
sudo gem install ruby-opencv -v '0.0.14'
```

Also, you may want to try changing from using `rvm` to using `ruby-build`.

Can you please edit your question, and add the results of the log file?

```
cat /home/k2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/ruby-opencv-0.0.14/gem_make.out
```

Have you already installed OpenCV successfully on its own?

You can install OpenCV with these instructions: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

If you can install OpenCV, that may help verify you have most of the pieces you need for the Ruby gem.

Comment: No root user, without root user only we can install, i think that's only better